# OpenCV on Erlang

Tags: opencv, erlang, erlang-ports

I would like to use **OpenCV** in my **Erlang** application. One solution would be to write an Erlang port etc., but I'm sure it has been done before.

The ideal result would be to be able to configure OpenCV from Erlang, and never touch a line of C code. But is this possible ? How would you do that ?

Comment: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-January/071945.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wrap the specific OpenCV configuration in a C application using the OpenCV C lib and call that app using Result = os:cmd('myapp'). That way you don't have to mess around with possible interoperability issues and have a clear separation between you C and Erlang code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I expect a constant flow of data coming from OpenCV to the Erlang app (real-time video processing).

Comment: Luopan, in that case I would communicate with the C program over a TCP socket.